# Programmatically triggering a long tap on a link in a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

Is there a way to programmatically trigger a long tap on a link inside a `UIWebView`, making the contextual menu Action Sheet appear?

I know it is possible to retrieve a link by its id and programmatically click it using `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('linkId').click;"];`

Is there any function I can replace `click` with to trigger a long tap instead of a regular left click?

Any solution that presents the context menu, not only with javascript, will work for me, as long as the presented menu is indeed the same that is presented after a long tap.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to present the context menu that appears after a long press on a link? If so, then you can simply do that programmatically, without tempering with javascript.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do. I do not need it to be a javascript based solution. I just provided some context on the direction I've been trying, but any solution that presents the context menu will solve my problem.

Comment: Just an idea, have you tried creating a long-press event in JavaScript and dispatching it to the link? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent

Answer (score 0):

You can simply present a `UIActionSheet` programmatically and make it look like that of a long press. Something like this:

```
UIActionSheet *ac = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Link Actions"
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                       otherButtonTitles:@"Open link in Safari", @"Copy link", nil];
```

Don't forget to implement the delegate method `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:`

Comment: I am sorry, I should have been more specific. I need to show the default contextual menu, specifically because of the "add to safari reading list" button.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it's possible. Also, I don't think you can imitate a long press on the link.